# Avoid duplicate code in statements like: isset($_GET['foo']['bar']) ? $_GET['foo']['bar'] : NULL;

Tags: php, coding-style, refactoring

To read unknown variables in PHP often I use code like the following:

```
$bar = isset($_GET['foo']['bar']) ? $_GET['foo']['bar'] : NULL;
```

I don't like to write the variable name twice. It just looks ugly and is too long for such an everyday task.

Do you know a better solution? Just using the `@` operator or suppress notices at all is no option (bad practice, slow).
With a custom function and variable by reference it is somehow possible:

```
function ifset(&$value)
{
    if(isset($value)) return $value;
}
$bar = ifset($_GET['foo']['bar']); // $_GET is empty
```

However this creates silently new unwanted variables with that name/path. A `var_dump($_GET)` would print:

```
array(1) {
  ["foo"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["bar"]=>
    NULL
  }
}
```

Comment: I think php has nothing for it. there are a lot of questions about it here.

Comment: I tried to find them but didn't know for what to search?

Comment: There are no other options. If you don't want to use PHPs dedicated syntax for this because of bad practice and slowness myths, you'll have to live with the cumbersome syntactic replica.

Comment: @mario: Maybe you are right. In most cases the the difference in speed is irrelevant. I just checked it. With my custom error handler `@` is 14 times slower than isset() (without error handler just 4 times). Anyway it takes just something arround 4 microseconds on my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally PHP7 brings a solution. *Yeah!* The [coalesce operator](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary).

```
$bar = $_GET['foo']['bar'] ?? NULL;
```

If the value before the `??` exists and is not `NULL` it returns that one, otherwise it takes the fallback value from behind the `??`. I love it!

Answer (score 2):

Although this will not completely solve your problem, in some cases you can use extract($_GET);

```
<?php

/* Suppose that $var_array is an array returned from
   wddx_deserialize */

$size = "large";
$var_array = array("color" => "blue",
                   "size"  => "medium",
                   "shape" => "sphere");
extract($var_array, EXTR_PREFIX_SAME, "wddx");

echo "$color, $size, $shape, $wddx_size\n";

?>
```

Comment: Creative, and it does at least make things look neater.

Answer (score 0):

Use : "eval(foo,bar") see in a php manual for: eval.

Comment: Do you mean `eval('return $foo')`?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to redesign your function would be to make a recursive function that adds all of the set keys into an array as names and then simply check using in_array() function.  If found, return value.

Comment: I tried that but didn't like it too. It is slow and you can't search for the full variable name anymore. Maybe IDEs with their code recognition will be irritated too?